# What is the best/more efficient way to send images to a server?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, image, http, base64

I have an AngularJS front-end which sends small and big images to an API. It encodes the image in `base64` and then send it into a `JSON` document.

Is there a best/faster way to do this ? Maybe not encoding the image but send a JavaScript `File` object ? Or something else ? (The images can be up to 5Mb).

Comment: An API is just a request for data; why're you serialising images as JSON?

Comment: Actually I don't know how to do it in another way. Could you explain please ? I just need to `POST` images to the API.

Answer (score 0):

There is a concept known as multipart-form data, that can be used for file upload. Java provides libraries to handle the uploaded file and save it in a location of our choice. Please tell me if you want me to share the exact implementation. I can do it for you. You just need a do post request to API.